# Minecraft auth server returning 403?

Tags: java, minecraft

So I'm trying to make a custom launcher for my custom Minecraft client but I need a session id to launch the game. This is the code I'm using to try and get a session ID:

```
package net.arachnamc;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String AUTH_SERVER = "https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate";
        String json = String.format(
                "{" +
                        "\"clientToken\":\"%s\"," +
                        "\"username\":\"%s\"," +
                        "\"password\":\"%s\"" +
                "}",


                UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                "Koolade446",
                "MyPasswordCensored"
        );
        JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(json);
        System.out.println(json);

        URL url = new URL(AUTH_SERVER);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        os.close();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();

    }
}
```

However, the server returns a 403 forbidden every time. I use a Microsoft account but I can't find any documentation on how to authenticate a Microsoft account so I assumed this was it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the auth server should be expecting some [oauth](https://oauth.net/2/) client.

Comment: This should be quite helpful: https://mojang-api-docs.netlify.app/authentication/msa.html in short if you are using a Microsoft account then you need to authenticate with the Microsoft servers